# Is TrueCrypt full disk encryption on windows 8 safe to use?

Tags: windows-8, truecrypt, disk-encryption

Since Windows 8 is currently still not 100% supported, I was wondering if full disk encryption is more or less safe to use in Windows 8.

I couldn't find any info on that on the internet, so I used a VM to simulate - everything worked there like a charm.

Does anyone have any experience with using TrueCrypt FDE on Windows 8, or knowledge about the portential risks (besides the obvious)?

Comment: I'd personally hang fire until they officially support it. Their website states a desire for this: http://www.truecrypt.org/future

Answer (score 0):

It's unknown until you try.

But it's not needed since Windows 8 now has "bitlocker" built-in tool that can do full drive encryption, even if you don't have hardware encryption module.

This tool is available from Windows 8 Pro and higher.